# Manipulate MySQL Database Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database that holds a list of classes in columns, and each class has a "level" which is the value of the row, which changes for each person. So, math, for example, has 0, 1, 2, and 3 as possible values, 0 being not selected as a class, and 1, 2, and 3 being high, medium, and low, respectively.

I have a MySQL query which pulls just the classes from a user's database row.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT math, physics, biology, chemistry, english, spanish, history, economics, art, theoryofknowledge, extendedessay FROM users WHERE username = '". $login_session ."'") or die(mysql_error());  

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
            echo "Math:". $row['math'] ."<br />";
            echo "Physics:". $row['physics'] ."<br />";
            echo "Biology:". $row['biology'] ."<br />";
            echo "Chemistry:". $row['chemistry'] ."<br />";
            echo "English:". $row['english'] ."<br />";
            echo "Spanish:". $row['spanish'] ."<br />";
            echo "History:". $row['history'] ."<br />";
            echo "Economics:". $row['economics'] ."<br />";
            echo "Art:". $row['art'] ."<br />";
            echo "Theory of Knowledge:". $row['theoryofknowledge'] ."<br />";
            echo "Extended Essay:". $row['extendedessay'];
        }
```

Here is the output for a user:

```
Math:1
Physics:1
Biology:0
Chemistry:2
English:2
Spanish:3
History:0
Economics:1
Art:0
Theory of Knowledge:1
Extended Essay:1
```

How could I determine which level a user has, without doing an if statement for every single time the class is called? I need to call the classes in multiple places on the site, and I'd like an easy way to check which classes, and level, the user has.

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a bit too nebulous to be answered.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Would you mind having a look at my answer then? I think you may have missed a great opportunity to set a fellow programmer on the path to clean OOP PHP code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to build a PHP class that loads the user in and inside it have a function that can accept a class (Biology, Math etc) and return the level of the user. If you wanted to, you could write something simple that performs a check of the level required and returns a true or false depending on if the user is a high enough level.

I even slapped together some super basic structure you might want to extend upon:

```
<?php

    class myUser
    // You are making an object here that stores information about your user.
    // This will mean you only need to query that data once from the DB, then
    // you can use it anywhere on the page without needing to do more queries.
    {
        public $math;
        public $biology;
        // I am making public variables here based on your columns
        // You cuold just as easily make an array for example to store them in.

        public function __construct($userID)
        // Making a construct class - meaning you will be able to write a snippet
        // like this: $currentUser = new myUser(6);
        // and the user information will be loaded nicely for you
        {
            $query="select math, biology from users where ID=$userID";
            // database stuff ....
            // this is where you would write your actual code to get the info
            // from the database and populate it properly, not like I did
            // below for this example
            $this->math=4;
            $this->biology=2;
        }

        public function checkUserLevel($myTopic, $reqLevel)
        // Making use of a few things here that I should ntoe:
        // This is a function you can call from the main code below
        // like this: $currentUser->checkUserLevel('math',3)
        // it will return either true or false.
        // I have used variable variables here for the $myTopic to
        // make it easier. You normally access an element differently
        // normally it is like: echo $this->math;  // output 4
        // Also I am using a ternary operator to return the data,
        // which is just a shortcut.
        {
            return ($this->$myTopic>=$reqLevel)? true : false;
        }

        public function returnUserLevel($myTopic)
        {
            return $this->$myTopic;
        }

    }

    $currentUser = new myUser(6);
    // This is creating a new user object based on the class we made above.
    // Further Explanation:
    // We have a class called myUser, but a class is just a schematic.
    // The $currenUser bit defines a new variable in our code.
    // the "= new myUser" bit says that we want to use the schematic above for this variable
    // the "myUser(6)" basically gives the constructor function an ID to get from
    // the database for the user. Because we defined a constructor class that expects
    // an ID, we need to supply it one, else we will get an error.
    // So $currentUser = new myUser(6)
    // really means "Make me a new variable called $currentUser and make it of the myUser
    // class type, and when making it, fetch me the details of student ID 6 and populate it
    // with their data.

    if($currentUser->checkUserLevel('math',3))
    // Now I am using one of the functions called checkUserLevel, supplying it
    // with the two arguments it needs and depending on it it returns true or false
    // doing one action or another.
    {
        echo "The user is at least level 3.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The user is lower than level 3.\n";
    }

    if($currentUser->checkUserLevel('biology',12))
    // same check, differnt inputs
    {
        echo "The user is at least level 3.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The user is lower than level 3.\n";
    }


    // You can output like this for example:
    echo "The users math is at: ".$currentUser->math;

    // and I added a little function that will simply return the level for you of the subject you enter.
    echo "The user is at math level ".$currentUser->returnUserLevel('math');

    // lastly you can do something like this:
    $allSubjects=array('math','physics','biology');
    for($i=0;$i<count($allSubjects);$i++)
    {
        echo "The users ".$allSubjects[$i]." level is at ".$currentUser->returnUserLevel($allSubjects[$i])."<br><br>";
    }

?>
```

The output of code is:

```
The user is at least level 3.

The user is lower than level 3.
```

Comment: I'm new to PHP, so could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @AlexCastro Yeah, I just added an edit with some example code for you :)

Comment: @AlexCastro Added tons of comments to explain what is happening in the code.

Comment: @AlexCastro Okay, added a pile more comments around the `$currentUser=new myUser(6);` line of code for you.

Comment: $currentUser = new myUser(6); Would I need to copy this line again and again in order to do the different checks, since this holds only one variable?

Comment: @AlexCastro The object I made would hold only one students details in it, but you could easily make an array of these objects if you needed more. Sorry, I assumed you were doing checks against a single student on each page?

Comment: @AlexCastro And if you use an object like I suggest, you will actually be able to store ALL of the students classes/levels in the one variable.

Comment: I am treating one person per page, I just didn't understand the code at first. I'm having some trouble with it working, mind taking a look here? http://pastebin.com/9cNnfe2L It seems to always default the values to one, even if I add a class that's not listed on the database, just to see.

Comment: @AlexCastro You have got the right idea, but around line 18-ish you need to actually GET the data from the database, you are making the query, but not actually running it by the looks of it. You need to run something like `while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))` in your original code then do the population part mate.

Comment: (It works, thanks a ton Fluffeh!) Any idea how I can cut down the statements like "if($currentUser->checkUserLevel('math',3))" since I have so many classes? I've uploaded a new paste here you can modify: http://pastebin.com/TA26Zk9v

Comment: @AlexCastro Looks like pastebin was down when I tried to make changes, but I edited my question based on what I saw. You should have a few more examples of what you can do now that will help you along.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to store the values of all classes in a PHP session variable when the user logs in:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["classes"] = array();       

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    foreach($row as $class => $level)
    {
        $_SESSION["classes"][$class] = $level;
    }
?>
```

Then you could access the user's class level on any page of your site until they close the session or log out:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $mathLevel = $_SESSION["classes"]["math"];
?>
```